# Tensorforce 'Adam' object has no attribute '_create_all_weights'

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have an M1 Mac, so I've created a virtual env with Python 3.9 and installed tensorforce 0.6.5 and I am trying to set up a simple agent and train it to play Snake. Here is my main code:

```
from tensorforce.agents import PPOAgent

from Game import Game
from SnakeEnvironment import SnakeEnvironment

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print(tensorforce.__version__)
    game = Game()
    environment = SnakeEnvironment(game)

    agent = PPOAgent(
        states=environment.states(),
        actions=environment.actions(),
        batch_size=128,
        max_episode_timesteps=100,
    )

    agent.initialize()

    for episodes in range(500):
        state = environment.reset()
        done = False

        while not done:
            actions = agent.act(states=state)

            next_state, done, reward = environment.execute(actions)

            agent.observe(terminal=done, reward=reward)

            state = next_state
    agent.save(directory='models')
```

But I am getting an error:

```
WARNING:root:No min_value bound specified for state.
WARNING:absl:At this time, the v2.11+ optimizer `tf.keras.optimizers.Adam` runs slowly on M1/M2 Macs, please use the legacy Keras optimizer instead, located at `tf.keras.optimizers.legacy.Adam`.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/dmytro/PycharmProjects/tensorforce/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/tensorforce/core/optimizers/tf_optimizer.py", line 142, in initialize_given_variables
    self.tf_optimizer._create_all_weights(var_list=variables)
AttributeError: 'Adam' object has no attribute '_create_all_weights'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/dmytro/PycharmProjects/tensorforce/main.py", line 19, in <module>
    agent.initialize()
  File "/Users/dmytro/PycharmProjects/tensorforce/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/tensorforce/agents/agent.py", line 280, in initialize
    self.model.initialize()
  File "/Users/dmytro/PycharmProjects/tensorforce/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/tensorforce/core/models/tensorforce.py", line 600, in initialize
    super().initialize()
  File "/Users/dmytro/PycharmProjects/tensorforce/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/tensorforce/core/models/model.py", line 290, in initialize
    self.core_initialize()
  File "/Users/dmytro/PycharmProjects/tensorforce/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/tensorforce/core/models/tensorforce.py", line 690, in core_initialize
    self.optimizer.initialize_given_variables(variables=self.policy.trainable_variables)
  File "/Users/dmytro/PycharmProjects/tensorforce/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/tensorforce/core/optimizers/optimizer.py", line 42, in initialize_given_variables
    module.initialize_given_variables(variables=variables)
  File "/Users/dmytro/PycharmProjects/tensorforce/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/tensorforce/core/optimizers/optimizer.py", line 42, in initialize_given_variables
    module.initialize_given_variables(variables=variables)
  File "/Users/dmytro/PycharmProjects/tensorforce/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/tensorforce/core/optimizers/optimizer.py", line 42, in initialize_given_variables
    module.initialize_given_variables(variables=variables)
  File "/Users/dmytro/PycharmProjects/tensorforce/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/tensorforce/core/optimizers/tf_optimizer.py", line 144, in initialize_given_variables
    self.tf_optimizer._create_hypers()
AttributeError: 'Adam' object has no attribute '_create_hypers'
```

I've also tried to run the same code on Windows 10 but the problem is still the same.
Any ideas how to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue while trying to load a tensorforce model through tensorforce.agents.Agent.load and the reason was TensorFlow version.
Try to install **tensorflow==2.8.0** after tensorforce installation.